# For which $a$ does this integral converge?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral

This is an exercise given during my course in Lebesgue integrals. I thought about it for two weeks but I couldn't find a solution. Do you have any hint?
The exercise asks to find for which values of $a\in\mathbb{R}$ the function $\frac{1}{n^2+x^{a}+2y^{a}+3z^{a}}$ is $L^1([0,+\infty)^3)$, for all $n\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$. Thank you very much!

Comment: Why use $3a$ if $a$ is an arbitrary real number?

Comment: Is, in this problem, $0\in \mathbb{N}$, or does $\mathbb{N}$ consist of only the strictly positive integers?

Comment: @zhw sorry, my mistake, of course $3$ is unuseful!

Comment: @DanielFischer  $n$ can be zero, thank you!

Comment: In that case, no such $a$ exists. For $n = 0$, the integral over $[0,1]^3$ is finite if and only if $a < 3$, and the integral over the rest is finite (whatever $n$ is) if and only if $a > 3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: You'll want to use Fubini. Note that

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{dt}{1+t^a}$$

converges iff $a>1.$ Note further that if $c>0,$ then

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{dt}{c+t^a} = c^{1/a-1}\int_0^\infty \frac{ds}{1+s^a}.$$

---

**Added later** Let's deal with just $1/(x^a+y^a+y^a).$ Using what I previously mentioned, the $x$ integral converges iff $a>1.$ In that case we get $C(y^a+z^a)^{1/a-1}.$ If we go to polar coordinates for the $y,z$ integral, we are then looking at

$$\left(\int_0^{\pi/2}(\cos^a t+ \sin^a t)^{1/a-1}\,dt \right )\left ( \int_0^\infty r^{2-a} \,dr \right ).$$

Note the $t$-integeral is nice and convergent for any $a.$

Comment: Actually I know I'd like to use Fubini, but unfortunately I cannot see how to reduce to such a form! Any suggestion?

Comment: @Zariski93 I added to my answer a bit.